# How to avoid the text jerk by using css transitions

Tags: css

I try to rotate the text by using, text-transform with transition. In firefox browser a slight jerk get happened. Check the below link, by mouse overing the text, end of the rotation you can see the slight jerk, how to avoid this?

```
.rot_pos{
    margin:100px auto;
    text-align:center;
    }
.rotate{
    font-size:30pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:inline-block;
    transform:rotate(0deg);
     -moz-transition:1s; 
    transition:1s;
}
.rotate:hover{
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);

}

<div class="rot_pos">
<div class="rotate">Sample Text</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/es86wh1p/

Any other solution??

This happens only in firefox.

Comment: While I dont have a direct answer on how to fix this behavior, 

it appears that the bounding box of the div is being modified on hover therefore the 'jerk' is being caused by a change in hover/normal state.

Comment: @DamianNikodem is that because of DIV? If i used any other element it will stop that behavior? Even i tried out with SPAN and some other elements, but firefox render it in same way. Is that issue belongs to browser or html?

Answer (score 0):

I had a small play with your code in js-fiddle, it almost appears to be a bug in firefox. A quick debugging tip for things like this is to enable borders and set different colors.

I was able to find a solution, but it is so incredibly hackey that this reminds me of the 90's and the fact that mozilla firefox rose from the ashes of the netscape codebase.

First I set a parent/child tag which "Should" have caused the text to rotate when the mouse entered the rot_pos div. This still caused the text to 'trap' when the mouse hit the box that was rotating ( when causing the mouse to leave quickly, you can test this by removing the padding from rot_pos )

Setting the Z-Order of rotate to -2 shows that the rotate:hover trigger is not being triggered when it is 'behind' another div. So the quick lazy fix would be to expand the size of rot_pos so it completely covers the rotating text.

Which leads me to: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rwa1pq2v/

```
.rot_pos{
    margin:100px auto;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 100px 20px 100px 20px;
    }
.rot_pos > .rotate {     
    font-size:31pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:inline-block;
    transform:rotate(0deg);        
    transition:1s;
    border: 1px solid black;    
    background: green;    
}
.rot_pos:hover > .rotate {        
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);           
}

.rotate {
    z-index: -2;
}
.rotate:hover {
    background: pink;    
}
```

The issue with this is that the rotation is being triggered when the mouse enters the outer-area. So with the knowledge that a div which is "above" according to the z-order will prevent the trigger of the div below I dropped a further 2 div's over the top which can be seen as red and blue with a opacity of 0.5 in the example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/non45qy2/

With some lazy hand fiddling of sizes to ensure that they completely cover the trigger area we have my final solution..

To improve on this we could also drop a further 2 div's to cover up the 2 leftover white area's (and fix up the padding on the covered up areas) so you don't have to offset by such a large amount.

if it wasn't 1:40am I would be raising this issue as a bug with mozilla and hoping it gets fixed in the next release.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply, i too thought of raising this issue to firefox. Will see...